# Manually fetch dependencies from go.mod?

Tags: go, go-modules

I'm using go 1.11 with module support. I understand that the go tool now installs dependencies automatically on build/install. I also understand the reasoning.

I'm using docker to build my binaries. In many other ecosystems its common to copy over your dependency manifest (package.json, requirements.txt, etc) and install dependencies as a separate stage from build. This takes advantage of docker's layer caching, and makes rebuilds much faster since generally code changes vastly outnumber dependency changes.

I was wondering if vgo has any way to do this?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

It was an issue [#26610](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/26610), which is fixed now.

So now you can just use:

```
go mod download
```

For this to work you need just the `go.mod` / `go.sum` files.

For example, here's how to have a cached multistage Docker build: ([source](https://www.docker.com/blog/containerize-your-go-developer-environment-part-1/))

```
FROM golang:1.17-alpine as builder
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates git
WORKDIR /build

# Fetch dependencies
COPY go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download

# Build
COPY . ./
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 go build

# Create final image
FROM alpine
WORKDIR /
COPY --from=builder /build/myapp .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["./myapp"]
```

---

Also see the article [Containerize Your Go Developer Environment – Part 2](https://www.docker.com/blog/containerize-your-go-developer-environment-part-2/), which describes how to leverage the *Go compiler cache* to speed up builds even further.

Comment: Not completely.  Commands like `go get -t -x` will still download more stuff.  Even after a `COPY . ./`, `go get -t -x` will download even more stuff, despite a tidy'd `go.mod`.  Where is the command to download *everything* from `go.mod`?

Comment: `go mod download` downloads exactly what's listed in `go.mod`, which should be enough to build and test the project. `go get` primary purpose is to add *new* dependencies or versions to the project. As a side effect it also populates the local cache.

Answer (score 26):

You may use the `go mod vendor` command which will create a `vendor` folder in the main module's root folder, and copy all dependencies into it. After this you may pass the `-mod=vendor` param to the go tool, and then dependencies from the `vendor` folder will be used to build / compile / test your app.

So what you may do to speed up your builds:

1. Run the `go mod vendor` command to have an actual version of your dependencies.
2. Save / cache this `vendor` folder.
3. During builds, restore this `vendor` folder, and build / install your app by passing the `-mod=vendor` argument to the go tool, so no dependencies will be downloaded, but the content of the `vendor` folder will be used.

Quoting from `go help mod`:

> Modules and vendoring
>
> When using modules, the go command completely ignores vendor directories.
>
> By default, the go command satisfies dependencies by downloading modules
>   from their sources and using those downloaded copies (after verification,
>   as described in the previous section). To allow interoperation with older
>   versions of Go, or to ensure that all files used for a build are stored
>   together in a single file tree, 'go mod vendor' creates a directory named
>   vendor in the root directory of the main module and stores there all the
>   packages from dependency modules that are needed to support builds and
>   tests of packages in the main module.
>
> To build using the main module's top-level vendor directory to satisfy
>   dependencies (disabling use of the usual network sources and local
>   caches), use 'go build -mod=vendor'. Note that only the main module's
>   top-level vendor directory is used; vendor directories in other locations
>   are still ignored.

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to re-download all the dependencies using `go mod`, this is what I did:

1. Go to your `GOROOT`
2. `sudo rm -rf pkg/mod/`
3. Go to the directory where the `go.mod` file exists
4. `go mod download`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a package manager, There are many of them like [dep](https://github.com/golang/dep), [glide](https://github.com/Masterminds/glide), and [govendor](https://github.com/kardianos/govendor). `dep` is newer and is going to be integrated into go toolchain as official dependency management tool.

We also make docker images for go applications and we use [dind](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/) to make those images and we prepared a CI/CD image with all dependencies preinstalled to make the builds faster. Though, it took a little bit of scripting to glue everything together.

Moreover, layering up the dependencies could result in big size of docker images. I suggest try [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) which could help making images super lite.

Comment: This is more a question of whether the new [modules](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules) system that landed in 1.11 has a built-in way to do this. If you check the dep repo, you'll see its actually being deprecated for modules :(